# Error while debugging an Android Widget

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging, android-widget

I have an Android Widget application. It is an application from [this page](http://looksok.wordpress.com/2012/12/15/android-complete-widget-tutorial-including-source-code/) (I just downloaded the source code).
For debugging this widget I user [this tutorial](http://tech.shantanugoel.com/2010/06/14/how-to-debug-android-widgets.html).
I put one breakpoint in the code (provided below).

```
public static void pushWidgetUpdate(Context context, RemoteViews remoteViews) {
Log.d("message", "fortunately, we have come to this point");

ComponentName myWidget = new ComponentName(context, MyWidgetProvider.class); //breakpoint is here!
AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
manager.updateAppWidget(myWidget, remoteViews);     
}
```

When I begin my debugging process, the green debugging line is shown on the line with the breakpoint as usual. But after several seconds it disappears, and I see that the widget (or the debugging process, or even the process on the phone itself) has been terminated. The process is no more in the process list in the DDMS perspective.
Why does the debugger suddenly stop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have read on StackOverflow, that debugging Android apps is better to do via logging (`Log.d(String tag, String log_text)`.
So, I have not found the reason of that error, just started to debug via logging.